# Swift 3 - Help Converting GCD class

Tags: ios, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I have a Grad Central Dispatch class which creates a timer written in swift 1.2.
I am trying to convert it into Swift 3 but cannot find the way to rewrite into swift 3.

Any help with this?

```
class GCDTimer {

    private var _timer : dispatch_source_t?

    init() {

    }

    private func _createTheTimer(interval : Double, queue : dispatch_queue_t, block : (() -> Void)) -> dispatch_source_t
    {
        let timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
        if (timer != nil)
        {
            dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), UInt64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)), (1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);
            dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
            dispatch_resume(timer);
        }
        return timer;
    }


    func start(interval : Double, block : (() -> Void))
    {
        let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        _timer = _createTheTimer(interval, queue: queue, block: block)

    }

    func stop()
    {
        if (_timer != nil) {
            dispatch_source_cancel(_timer!);
            _timer = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too broad. Stack Overflow is not a translation service. "Cannot find the way to rewrite" is not a real problem. "Any help with this?" is not a real question. If you have specific problems / errors, ask about one of them. — Meanwhile, here is my own GCD-based timer; feel free to use it. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p499cancelableTimer/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift

Comment: @matt i see you have a lot of iOS related points, can you tell me what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here, i used Xcode convert option for it:

Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax

```
class GCDTimer {

    fileprivate var _timer : DispatchSource?

    init() {

    }

    fileprivate func _createTheTimer(_ interval : Double, queue : DispatchQueue, block : (() -> Void)) -> DispatchSource {
        let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags(rawValue: 0), queue: queue);
        if (timer != nil) {
            timer.setTimer(start: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), interval: UInt64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)), leeway: (1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);
            timer.setEventHandler(handler: block);
            timer.resume();
        }
        return timer as! DispatchSource;
    }


    func start(_ interval : Double, block : (() -> Void)) {
        let queue = DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default);

        _timer = _createTheTimer(interval, queue: queue, block: block)

    }

    func stop() {
        if (_timer != nil) {
            _timer!.cancel();
            _timer = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

After gruntwork ;)

```
class GCDTimer {

    var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?
    init() { }

    func startTimer(deadline: DispatchTime,interval: DispatchTimeInterval,queue: DispatchQueue,
                leeway: DispatchTimeInterval, block : @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
        timer?.scheduleRepeating(deadline: deadline, interval: interval, leeway: leeway)
        timer?.setEventHandler {
        block()
        }
    timer?.resume()
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you .. I have already tried this but still get errors on lines

Comment: Yeah, the converter is not perfect, from Swift 1 to 3 there was always gruntwork ;)